# What does 'real(10, 7)' mean?

Tags: sql, types

I was studying an algorithm book that faced to the following sentence. Please describe it for me.

***real (10,7)**: The real(10,7) data type denotes a real number with a precision of seven significant digits.*

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`REAL`](http://floating-point-gui.de/languages/sql/) is defined in the SQL standard as a [binary floating-point](http://floating-point-gui.de/formats/fp/) type. However, AFAIK its precision is implementation-dependant (typically IEEE 754 single or double precision, i.e. your regular 32 or 64 bit floats). This may be a mistake in the book, or a proprietary extension of the standard.

Answer (score 0):

A REAL(10,7) datatype in SQL is like an decimal(10,7). It means that you have a number like 1234567890.0000001

Comment: Actually, REAL is a binary type and thus absolutely *not* like DECIMAL.

Comment: @Michael: giving him the benefit of the doubt, I read the answer as meaning that the syntax was the same, rather than the end result. But you're right; it is a completely different type of data (especially for values like the one he used as an example!)

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case it means that you will have an number with 10 digits in total: 3 of them can be on the left side of the decimal point, 7 on the right side.

e.g. 123.1234567

In mathematics however, a significant digit denote the leftmost number after a decimal point that is non-zero and all consecutive numbers:

e.g 0.00000123 would have 3 significant digits in the scientific sense (see: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) for more information).